# What stops a work of prose from having poetic parts?

Tags: creative-writing

After years of reading science or non-fiction books, I spent the last months in the world of fiction. I always enjoyed myths, legends, and narratives, but in different forms of media.

It is remarkable how many genres and categories are in writing, I am equally fascinated from reading the theory as well as reading actual writings.

Poetry, from what I understand, is focused on expressing the emotions while presenting the details in an expected way (rhythm, metre, and so on).

Novels are usually prose, but what stops them from having poetic parts? For example, when I read crime fiction (Dan Brown keeps me busy lately), there are times where everything freezes and the author does an excellent job of sending you the feelings and the agony of the characters while also the detail in the atmosphere. There is no verse, of course, but the emotions are there and indeed if you put breaks while you read it (and not read like a robot) it does feel like a freestyle poem.

I know it's not the intention of the author, nor it is the market group of novels to belong in poetry. Bu apart from those external factors, internally what differentiates a chapter of a novel devoted to the lyrical expression of the situation from a poem?

Comment: Nothing, surely...

Answer (score 2):

There have in fact been novels in verse, although not very many of them. Plays in verse are rather more common, but still unusual.. It is quite common for novels tyo include short segments of verse, either written by the author or quoted from else where.

There are also rare cases of novels formatted as prose but that read as verse, for example Thurber's *The Thirteen Clocks*.

It was once usual for a long work to be in verse: *Paradise Lost* comes to mind, as does *Beowulf*, and *The Iliad*

As for being poetic in a wider sense, expressing emotions, having a lyrical sense, and focusing on imagery,  many prose works do this to a greater or lesser extent.

So I woulds say the only formal distinction is the use of a verse form, and that may not be very important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
This is what i thought so. Sometimes a prose has the rythm/metric. The author may not put breaks for verse but it is there, you can see it while reading loud.